# Access Global Variables Within Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just created an app that's using a lot of fragments to work with. I created Viewpager with more than 10 fragments in it. Now what I wanna try is set the variables from a fragment so it can be accessed on another fragment.

What have I tried so far. I create global variable to store the value

```
public class DataSite extends Application {

private String someVar;

public String getSomeVar(){
    return someVar;
}

public void setSomeVar(String someVar){
    this.someVar = someVar;
}
```

}

In fragment A. I set the value like below

```
((DataSite) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).setSomeVar("Tes");
```

And from other fragment I tried to get the value like this

```
((DataSite)getActivity().getApplication()).getSomeVar();
```

But as soon as I click the button in fragment A, which the app is trying to set var to global class....The app suddenly crashed and no error logcat showed in Android Studio.

Maybe anyone can explain why this happen

Comment: have you added application in manifest?

Comment: If you want this variable to be accessible in only these fragments then you should make it global on `Activity` level (the one that contains all these fragments) and not on `Application` level. Because anyone within this application can change application level variable.

Comment: Secondly try to replace `((DataSite) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).setSomeVar("Tes");` with `((DataSite) getActivity().getApplication()).setSomeVar("Tes");`

Comment: so I supposed extends Activity instead of Application?

Comment: No, you should remove this code from `Application` class into `Activity` class, the `Activity` which has these fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add your customise application class in manifest as

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.some.somemore">

    <application
        android:name=".DataSite"
      ....> </application>
```

Comment: what if I gave more than one application class?

Comment: @BrenDonie why would you want to do that?

Comment: @BrenDonie there can be only one application class in a project

Comment: Cus the variables are too many to be contained in just one class. But I figured out the way. Thanks @BugsHappen

Answer (score 1):

`((DataSite)getActivity().getApplication()).getSomeVar();` //this is correct

`((DataSite) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).setSomeVar("Tes");` //this is wrong

`.getApplication()` is correct way